# PHP select current time in cell

Tags: php

If I use PHP code like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++)
 {
 $timetable=strftime("%X", mktime(0, 0, $hour[$i], $month, $day, $year));
 }
```

to get timetable for current day that looks like:

```
   time   |
 ----------
 05:09:23 |
 ----------
 07:23:18 |
 ----------
 11:55:41 |
 ----------
 14:01:32 |
 ----------
```

I want to highlight cell where the printed time include the current time (if the current time is 9:23:00 highlight cell will be the one with the printed time 07:23:18 and if the current time is 13:59:06 highlight cell will be 11:55:41)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to do it:

```
$thisID = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++)
{
    $tt = mktime(0, 0, $hour[$i], $month, $day, $year);
    $timetable = strftime("%X", $tt);

    if($thisID == 0 && (time() - $tt) >= 0)
         $thisID = $i;
}
```

Now `$thisID` gives you the required row. Use it to highlight the row.

Comment: thanks but I'm geting this error "Fatal error: Function name must be a string" in  line whre is " if($time() - $tt >= 0)". What can be the problem?

Comment: I updated the code a few minutes later I posted it. Did you try the new code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a date_diff() function you can use to determine which one is closest.  [link date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)  Or, if this info is coming from the database, you can use your database's date/time handling functions to return the time difference between Now() and the date being pulled back as a column.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this In my opinion is to store the times in unix timestamps or seconds from midnight. This way you have a solid way of sorting your data.

To get the closest record you will need to do 2 queries.

```
Select time from times where time > $value order by time desc limit 1
Select time from times where time < $value order by time asc limit 1
```

Now compare these 2 results to $value and return the closest one.

Although this method requires 2 queries and uses a greater/less than statement, I think ist is faster than retrieving all data.

Hope this helps!